# C# acces property from abstract classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a class structure like this:

BaseAnimal.cs:

```
public abstract class BaseAnimal
{
   public string? Species { get; set; }
   public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have this two classes:

```
public abstract class Carnivore : BaseAnimal
{
    public double MeatFood { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Herbivore : BaseAnimal
{
   public double GreenFood { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have the sub classes:

```
public class Ape : Herbivore
{
    public Ape()
    {
        Species = "Ape";
        GreenFood = 10.0;
        Price = 10000.0;
    }
}
```

Then I have a facotry which is already working with this line to get all the attributes from an animal:

```
public BaseAnimal[] Animals = prototypes.Values.ToArray();
```

And in my Main class I would like to read the properties of the Animals:

```
 private void cboAnimals_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    Debug.WriteLine(animalFactory.Animals[0].);
 }
```

The problem with this code is, that I cannot access the properties specified in the Herbivore.cs and Carnivore.cs

Comment: That's not how it works; Animals is a lmn array of a base class. When you use something in a context that only knows about base classes (such as the animals array) you can only access properties of the base class. You could cast the Animal in slot 0 to the Herbivore or Carnivore or Ape you know it to be but then you're breaking the idea of the abstraction that the Main class is capable of dealing with an Animal as just an Animal

Comment: If you want Main to be able to carry out animal specific behavior you build the specific behavior into the subclass as an override of an abstract feature on the base class. Main then calls on the thing it can see e.g. the virtual Speak() method, and if the Animal is an Ape (that overrides Speak to say "oo oo aa aa") you hear a different sound to if the animal is a Cow (whose Speak overrides to say "moo")

Comment: May be redundant with other comments but, gonna try. Your `BaseAnimal[] Animals` because of its type `BaseAnimal` you can access only its `Species` and `Price` properties. You could direct cast it to an inherited type but you should check if the underlying type is the desired type to avoid errors `if (Animals[0] is Herbivore) Debug.WriteLine(((Herbivore)Animals[0]).GreenFood);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simplest is probably to check the type:

```
var foodAmount = animalFactory.Animals[0] switch {
     Carnivore c => c.MeatFood ,
    Herbivore h => h.GreenFood ,
    _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
};
```

But this is a typical example of inheritance taught in introductory programming. As a general rule, if you need to check the type, you might not have thought thru your type system well enough. The idea with inheritance is that everything implementation specific should be delegated to the implementation, so the user of the object do not need to know the concrete type.

I have some difficulty providing concrete recommendations since the example is so artificial, But I would recommend reading Eric Lippert series on [Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) for a nice introduction to inheritance, and how people often do it wrong.

Comment: alright, thanks!!

Comment: I would even say, DON'T do inheritance. You should favor "Composition" 
This will ease your life, make your code testable, and reuse code in a safe way.

Comment: @Morten Bork I'm assuming this is for some school assignment. While composition over inheritance is a good idea, it might not be relevant in a class *about* inheritance.

Comment: @JonasH sure, but why the hell, is the school teaching inheritance when they should be teaching composition?

Comment: @Morten Bork There are a ton of things I think is often poorly taught in programming, usually including inheritance. I still think it should be taught, but when, and when not to use it should absolutely be included. The example about animals would be a typical bad example of inheritance. But we are not here to reform the school system, the best I can do is point towards better sources of knowledge.

Comment: @JonasH Agreed, which is why I pointed to composition. 

And while I am not here to reform the school system, I am here to reform bad programming practices. 
If a school is actively teaching this stuff, then the context is super important. 

This is not a "home-work" site, this is a serious programming site. 
And we should treat the problems as such. 

If you make a bad paradigm choice in solving a problem, your approach is to shift paradigm, not explore an inferior method further.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is use Composition.

```
public interface IFood {

   public double Food { get; set; }
}

public class Herbivore {

   public double Food { get; set; }
}

public class Carnivore {

   public double Food { get; set; }
}

public interface IAnimal {
   string? Species { get; set; }
   double Price { get; set; }
}

public class Animal {
   string? Species { get; set; }
   double Price { get; set; }
}

public class Ape {
   private IAnimal _animal;
   private IFood _food;

   public Ape(IAnimal animal, IFood food) {
      _animal = animal;
      _food = food;
   }
}



public void main(string[] args) {

      IFood herbivore = new Herbivore(){Food = 10};
      IAnimal ape = new Animal(){
         Price = 1000;
         Species = "Ape";
      };
      Ape ape = new Ape(ape, herbivore);
   }

Now you can compose any class of type animal you want, you can reuse the implementation of IAnimal and IFood on other types, make new ones? Like Omnivore?
```

you can implement different species, and or "price" and load it into any new class like "dog" or "cat" you want, and compose that object with your Interfaces. Thus not needing to rewrite your tests, you don't need to have multiple implementations of say ... "Speak" on dogs that all do a "bark" you can have one class that does "bark" and then compose it into all dog like animals.

Just consider how easy it is now to implement a behaviour like "consume" that will work across all herbivores, omnivores or carnivores?

You only have to write 3 unit tests, one for each, not one for each animal type you eventually create, because they exist with dependency separation.

And Consume would work on any parameter of type food, so you don't even have to care if you find new ways of defining food, like a rock-eater or something :)

or if you had to descript plants, as something that "consumes" and you needed sunlight as a food source? Super simple to do, You wouldn't need to write x-amount of plant type unit tests for that either.

Composition over inheritance is by far the better choice to implement code in OOP.

Answer (score -1):

`Animals` is an array of `BaseAnimal`. This class doesn't have a `MeatFood` or a `GreenFood` property. That's why you can't access these properties. If you could access them, this code would be possible:

```
BaseAnimal animal = new Ape();
Console.WriteLine(animal.MeatFood);
```

But `Ape` has no `MeatFood` property. If you want to access these properties, you have know whether your `Animals[0]` is a `Carnivore` or a `Herbivore`:

```
private void cboAnimals_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    if(animalFactory.Animals[0] is Carnivore carnivore)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(carnivore.MeatFood);
    }
    else if (animalFactory.Animals[0] is Herbivore herbivore)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(herbivore.GreenFood);
    }
 }
```

But maybe you realize at this point that you won't get good code by this. This is a sign that your class structure is not the best. In fact, why do you have two properties `MeatFood` and `GreenFood`? What is the difference between them? Both are of a double type. Hence maybe you should have a `Food` property in your `BaseAnimal` class and distinguish the type of food by an enum:

```
public enum FoodType
{
   Meat,
   Green
}

public abstract class BaseAnimal
{
   public string? Species { get; set; }
   public double Price { get; set; }
   public double Food { get; set;}
   public abstract FoodType FoodType {get;}
}

public abstract class Carnivore : BaseAnimal
{
    public override FoodType FoodType{ get { return FoodType.Meat; } }
}

public abstract class Herbivore : BaseAnimal
{
   public override FoodType FoodType{ get { return FoodType.Green; } }
}
```

Comment: Please use this as an opportunity to teach polymorphism; saying "you could do this ... but you shouldn't" without including what should be done isn't a very helpful learning experience for the OP

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that animals array is of type BaseAnimal. You'll need to unbox it (ie cast it to it's subtype), you'll need some logic to check the type also, so something like

```
if (obj is Herbivore) 
{
   var herb = (Herbivore)obj;
   herb.Greenfood= 123m;
}
```

It seems messy but at some point you need to get the concrete type.